# Android ,No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'TensorArrayWriteV3' with these attrs

Tags: python, android, tensorflow

I'm trying to deploy the .pb model to Android, but I threw this error during the execution process. I haven't located the problem at present.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.lancer.photopainting, PID: 28374
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'TensorArrayWriteV3' with these attrs.  Registered devices: [CPU], Registered kernels:
      device='CPU'; T in [DT_BOOL]
      device='CPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT]
      device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT32]
    
         [[Node: map_4/while/TensorArrayWrite/TensorArrayWriteV3 = TensorArrayWriteV3[T=DT_UINT8, _class=["loc:@map_4/while/convert_image"]](map_4/while/TensorArrayWrite/TensorArrayWriteV3/Enter, map_4/while/Identity_1, map_4/while/convert_image, map_4/while/Identity_2)]]
        at org.tensorflow.Session.run(Native Method)
        at org.tensorflow.Session.access$100(Session.java:48)
        at org.tensorflow.Session$Runner.runHelper(Session.java:298)
        at org.tensorflow.Session$Runner.run(Session.java:248)
        at org.tensorflow.contrib.android.TensorFlowInferenceInterface.run(TensorFlowInferenceInterface.java:228)
        at org.tensorflow.contrib.android.TensorFlowInferenceInterface.run(TensorFlowInferenceInterface.java:197)
        at org.tensorflow.contrib.android.TensorFlowInferenceInterface.run(TensorFlowInferenceInterface.java:187)
        at com.lancer.photopainting.utils.PredictionTF.stylizeImage(PredictionTF.java:69)
        at com.lancer.photopainting.utils.PredictionTF.getPredict(PredictionTF.java:50)
        at com.lancer.photopainting.MainActivity.lambda$initActivity$3$com-lancer-photopainting-MainActivity(MainActivity.java:103)
        at com.lancer.photopainting.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda3.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7506)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7483)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:838)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28730)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8164)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:656)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 28374 SIG: 9
```

Can someone help me locate the problem? Maybe it's the problem of model algorithm, but I really have no idea.

Comment: You might want to describe/confirm what type of model you are running on Android, as Tensorflow Lite has [restrictions compared to normal Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_compatibility).

Comment: I didn't use TensorFlow lite. Here are the dependencies I added:
implementation 'org. Tensorflow: Tensorflow android: 1.13.1
I'm not sure whether this problem is due to the model training process.

Comment: Sadly support for direct Tensorflow on Android may be limited as noted in this [issue ticket comment](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/40350#issuecomment-644829225) and that that tensorflow-android 1.13.1 hasn't been updated since Feb 2019. At a guess, your current model may be using newer features of TensorArray that not in the older version 1.13.1.